# C# List not comparing with equals operator

Tags: c#, list, collections

I am comparing two lists in C#. Here is the basic code

```
List<string> expectedTabs = new List<string>() { "Batch", "Card Services", "ReportingXXXXX" };

List<string> actualTabs = new List<string>() { "Batch", "Card Services", "Reporting" };

string [] text = new string[actualTabs.Count];

int i = 0;

foreach (IWebElement element in actualTabs)
{
     text[i++] = element;
     Console.WriteLine("Tab Text : " + text[i - 1]);
}

for(int x = 0; x < actualTabs.Count; x++)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedTabs.Count == actualTabs.Count); //this gives equal count
    Console.WriteLine(expectedTabs[x] + " :: " + actualTabs[x]);

    expectedTabs[x].Equals(actualTabs[x]); //Gives wrong result here

    Console.WriteLine(expectedTabs.GetType()); //returns type as collection.list
}
```

Now the equal should return false when comparing the last element `[ReportingXXXXX and Reporting]` in both the lists, but it just gives the result as equal. I am not sure if I need to use something else here.

Comment: How you have checked it? You don't assign the result of `Equals` to any variable. Just in the debugger?

Comment: It will be a little easier if you add the console output

Comment: I think you meant to use `Assert.Equals ( expectedTabs[x],(actualTabs[x]);` instead

Comment: the line `expectedTabs[x].Equals(actualTabs[x]);` gives correct results. Check out yourself in debugger. Can you tell more what you're trying to achieve?. There could be several ways to accomplish the results.

Comment: When I do `var equal = expectedTabs[x].Equals(actualTabs[x]);` I get false for the final one. Where are you seeing `true`?

Comment: Tested your code, it works correctly on my machine. `expectedTabs[x].Equals(actualTabs[x])` yields false for `ReportingXXXXX :: Reporting`. Also that block where you fill `text` appears to be irrelevant (Edit 1: and wrong, `actualTabs` doesn't have any `IWebElement`, so I tested without that part). Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Edit 2: Did you ask a question anyway?

Answer (score -1):

reducing your code to what I think is the relevant bits...

```
var expectedTabs = new List<string>() { "Batch", "Card Services", "ReportingXXXXX" };
var actualTabs = new List<string>() { "Batch", "Card Services", "Reporting" };
for (var x = 0; x < actualTabs.Count; x++)
{
   var equal = expectedTabs[x].Equals(actualTabs[x]); //Gives wrong result here
   Console.WriteLine(equal);
}
```

This produces

```
True
True
False
```

Where are you seeing the wrong result?

Your code / comparison works fine.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer.